# Imagemagick feather edges of object on png with transperency background

Tags: imagemagick

[1.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EoKA.jpg)   [11.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wICPS.jpg)I have a question, how to do this, as in the example with a photograph, but in iamge Magick, feather the edge of an object on a transparent background so that you get a soft gradient and transition when overlaying the object on the original photo so that the mask has soft borders and does not have any edges after editing clear boundaries

Link to an example with photos from Photoshop - https://myphotoshop.ru/kak-razmyt-kraya-izobrazheniya/
Interested in the first option of blurring using feathering

thank you in advance

i dont know how to do this in magick, only trying on ps and its works, but i need magick to automate this process

Answer (score 2):

Using ImageMagick v7, this Windows CLI command will isolate an area of an image, blur the outer edges of that area, and leave it on a transparent background.

```
magick lena.png -fill white -background none ^
   ( +clone -evaluate set 0 -draw "arc 200,150 370,420 0,360" -blur 0x24 ) ^
   -alpha off -compose copyopacity -composite result.png
```

That command starts by reading in the image. Then inside the parentheses it makes a clone, makes it black, draws a white oval on it, then blurs the oval. After the parentheses it uses the compose method "copyopacity" to composite that white-on-black mask onto the input image. The white areas of the mask will be visible in the result. The black areas will be transparent.

The input and output of the command...

[image]

[image]

EDITED TO ADD:
You can use the same sort of masked composite to modify just a part of an image.

```
magick lena.png -background none -fill red ^
   ( +clone -tint 100 ) -fill white ^
   ( +clone -evaluate set 0 -draw "arc 200,150 370,420 0,360" -blur 0x24 ) ^
   -swap 0,1 -alpha off -composite result2.png
```

This command reads in the image, in parentheses makes a clone and manipulates it however you like, and in parentheses again it makes the white-on-black mask. Then after the parentheses it uses "-swap" to arrange the modified version, the original, and the mask in that order, then composites with this result.

[image]

To use these commands on a *nix OS, change the continued-line carets "^" to backslashes "\", and escape the parentheses with backslashes "\(...\)". I think that should be the only changes needed.

Find out more about using "-draw" to make a mask [AT THIS LINK](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/).

Comment: i need to make from 1.png result like on 11.png look in example in question im add photo

Comment: im add in text 1.png and 11.png with feathered edges

Comment: how i can make same result with magick?

Comment: See my edit for an additional example.

Comment: How i can do this using bit mask to choose the skin on my png to make feather to edges of skin?

Comment: If you need more than the basic transparency masking methods in these commands, you would have to post some example images that show your original and the intended result.